# Laravel 5 data into view

Tags: php, laravel-5, syntax-error

At the moment in my controller I am doing the following

```
$clients = Client::lists('clientName');
dd($clients);
```

The above outputs an array as expected

```
Collection {#182 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => "John Dandy"
    1 => "Jane Doe"
    2 => "Nicholas"
  ]
}
```

So I continue to pass this data to my view

```
return View::make('projects.create', compact('clients'));
```

So I know clients contains data as confirmed by the dd dump.  However, in my view, if I do `{!! $clients !!}`, I get the error

> FatalErrorException in 887e98b93946af76e5541ac7ae310735 line 49:
>   syntax error, unexpected 'null' (T_STRING)

Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you sure line 49 is the one were you try to output clients and not something else?

Answer (score 0):

It is a collection, so you cannot directly display it. The following might do :)

```
@foreach($clients as $client)
    {{ $client }}
@endforech
```